# Getting error on connecting to a local SQL Server database to databricks via JDBC connection

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, sqljdbc

Basically I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database on my local machine from databricks using a JDBC connection. I'm following the procedure mentioned in the documentation as shown here on the [databricks website.](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#python-example)

I used the following code as mentioned on the website:

```
jdbcHostname = "localhost"
jdbcDatabase = "TestDB"
jdbcPort = "3306"

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
    "jdbcUsername" : "user1",
    "jdbcPassword" : "pass1",
    "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     }

pushdown_query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.customer"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query,properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

But I'm getting this error

> IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection. Check the URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB

Can anyone explain why is it happening? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Usually `3306` port used for mysql databases.

Try with **`1433`** port for **`Sql server databases`**.

in jdbc url use sqlserver instead of mysql **`jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};databaseName={2}"`**

---

`Example Jdbc url:`

**`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks`**

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 1433/TestDB is not valid.

Comment: Try with `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDB`