# Connection refused on connecting to postgresql:dbserver db to Databricks via JDBC connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to connect to a postgresql database on my local machine from databricks using a JDBC connection. There are several useful posts in stackoverflow. I'm following the procedure mentioned in the documentation in [spark.apache.org](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) and [databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#python-example) website.

also these posts : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624059/getting-error-on-connecting-to-a-local-sql-server-database-to-databricks-via-jdb/62624144#62624144) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825734/postgresql-connection-refused-check-that-the-hostname-and-port-are-correct-an) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904997/connection-refused-pgerror-postgresql-and-rails)

In RStudio I can connect to postgresql database via this script :

```
# Define data base credential ----
psql <- DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con <- dbConnect(
  psql,
  dbname = 'mydbname',
  host = 'hostname',
  port = 5444,
  user = 'username',
  password = 'password')
```

I am trying to connect postgresql via JDBC to databricks. I used two approaches:

```
    # method 1
    jdbcHostname = "hostname"
    jdbcDatabase = "mydbname"
    jdbcPort = 5444
    
    
    jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
    connectionProperties = {
      "user" : "username",
      "password" : "password",
      "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver"
    }
pushdown_query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table= pushdown_query , properties=connectionProperties)
```

and this one

```
#method2
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5444/mydbname") \
    .option("dbtable", "SELECT * FROM schema.mytable") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password")\
    .load()
```

but I am getting error on both tries like this :

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

I couldn't understand why it tries to connect to `localhost:5432` when I specified `localhost:5444`?

Comment: Why are you putting `dbserver` in your connection string?

Comment: it was in Spark Apache spark documentation , without dbserver , the error is the connection attempt failed

Comment: In your RStudio example, your username is `username`.  In the others it is `user`.

Comment: yeah, but the password and username are something else and identical , i will edit my post to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Check the following file in intelij "**application.properties**" for example:

specifically: Username, Password, Port(this case: 5432) and make sure you actually created the database by its name(this case: 'student') before and its consist with this lines for example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

server.error.include-message=always
```

Comment: Question is about Spark, not Spring

Comment: I guess I missed it somehow. Thank you for correcting me.